# SVGZ doesn't display

Tags: html, css, svg, svgz

SVGZ format only works when I test it on local on Google Chrome. (doesn't work on other browers) 
It worked fine with svg though.
Otherwise, on server, it doesn't work. I tried to add a .htaccess file with the lines

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
AddEncoding x-gzip .svgz
```

But it still doesn't work. Tried it inline and background, same result.

[Here's the link to my test](http://aurelieremia.be/test/)

I tried it in multiple background (with texture), and on the bottom of the page in inline.

I'm stuck.

Comment: test link return error

Answer (score 3):

**httpd.conf & mime.types**

`httpd.conf` is located at `apache/conf/httpd.conf`. Ensure that these two lines are there:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

Alternatively you can only add the `AddEncoding` line and take care of the mime type via `mime.types` in the same directory. Ensure that the following line is there:

```
image/svg+xml svg svgz
```

Restart Apache then clear the browser's cache, reload, and check the headers.